# Я не знаю механизма, какой позволяет реализовать данный код

Tags: javascript, объекты

```js
'use strict';
let prototypeToDebts = {
        n: 6,
        fullDebt : function(){
            //some code
        },
        debtToEmpty : function(){
            //some code
        },
        pushToServ: function(sum){
            //some code
        },
        pushFromServ: function(sum){//getting some new dept
            //some code
        },
    }; 
let debts = {
    prototype: prototypeToDebts,// мне казалось что это можно реализовать таким образом, но я ошибся...
    user1:{ 
        //some code
    },
    user2:{
        //some code
    },
};
console.log(debts.user1.n);// должно выдать 6
console.log(debts.user2.n);// должно выдать 6
```

Это просто пример, но суть понятна: у меня в объекте depts есть объекты которые будут добавляться, и я хочу чтобы у всех дочерних от debts объектов были определенные свойства и методы, без необходимости записать их в каждый user по отдельности.

Comment: Почему бы вам не использовать классы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- У debts и у user в вашем примере общий прототип.
- Создайте классы для User и для Debts и им уже присваивайте нужные 
  свойства.

```js
'use strict'
//Класс для юзера
class User {
    constructor(name = "Anonymous") {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

//Класс для дебс
class Debts {
  //для примера юзеры будут складываться в массив
  constructor (users = []){
    this.users = users;
  }
    add (user) {
      this.users.push(user)
      }
    fullDebt() {
        //some code
    }
    debtToEmpty() {
        //some code
    }
    pushToServ(sum) {
        //some code
    }
    pushFromServ(sum) { //getting some new dept
        //some code
    }
}

//Если надо именно через прототипирование, можно так, либо сразу в User свойство нужное прописать.
User.prototype.n=6;

//создаем новый дебс, можно и так new Debts([(new User("Вася"), new User("Петя")])
let debts = new Debts();

//добавляем юзеров
debts.add(new User("Вася"))
debts.add(new User("Петя"))

console.log(debts.users[0].n);
console.log(debts.users[1].n);
```

Answer (score 0):

Для создания объекта на основе другого объекта можно воспользоваться функцией [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties)

```js
'use strict';
let prototypeToDebts = {
  n: 6,
  fullDebt: function() {
    //some code
  },
  debtToEmpty: function() {
    //some code
  },
  pushToServ: function(sum) {
    //some code
  },
  pushFromServ: function(sum) { //getting some new dept
    //some code
  },
};
let debts = {
  user1: Object.create(prototypeToDebts),
  user2: Object.create(prototypeToDebts),
};
console.log(debts.user1.n); // должно выдать 6
console.log(debts.user2.n); // должно выдать 6
```